# Game Maker Studio 2 (GMS2), game is launching in a localhost browser?

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-studio-2

Today I opened my gms2 and launched my game.
The game launched into my webbrowser with a GMWebServer

This has never happened to me before and I do not know how to stop this. The game used to launch into its own application executable. I do not want it to launch into this webserver, the game does not look the same.

Does anyone know what is happening? How do I disable this?
[GMWebServer] GMWebServer started successfully on port 51264

Is there a way to return back to the previous way the game would launch? Into its own application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'm from brazil, so, sorry for my english, i found how to open the project inside of gamemaker instead of browser, in the right side of the screen there's a few options, you have to switch the "gx.games" to "test" on targets. probably will be these 4 options for you, "GX.games | VM | Default | Default", i tried to send screenshots but i can't because the server returns an error, anyway, good luck.

Comment: thank you so much for this! im glad it was an easy fix. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a target icon at the corner of your screen in the GMS2 app, if you press this different selections show up. To fix your problem, turn the GX.games selection to Test. This should fix it.